# Deploying AzureDevOps Build Artifacts

Tags: azure-devops, azure-functions

I have a solution in Azure Devops. This is for Azure function. I am using the build pipeline to generate a artifact. This artifact I need to deploy it through powershell, I am using kudo API to deploy this.

```
https://$appName.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zipdeploy
```

The issue is the format which Azure DevOps generates completely different from msdeploy in visual studio generates. When I deploy the zip file generated from vs it gets deployed correctly. Can I make Azure Devops to generate the Artifact same as visual studio

***Adding more information as per comment***

---

I am using Visual Studio Build Task to generate build and Publish task to publish artifact
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/visual-studio-build?view=azure-devops
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops

The generated artifact with zip has a high depth something like "\publish\Content\D_C\a\1\s\src\aadsr\aadsr\obj\Release\net461\PubTmp\Out".
I just want the zip file should have content of Out folder, which I directly want to publish to a function APP

[image]
[image]

Comment: As what you mentioned, you hope the artifact which Azure Devops generated is same as Visual Studio, did you want the artifact is a ZIP file?

Comment: May I know how did you generate the zip from devops ? I download the zip from devops but the artifact is same as the zip from visual studio. So could you please share the screenshot of the artifact generated in your devops ?

Comment: See this: https://imgur.com/a/zdHqS4P . Isn't you want is a ZIP file?

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT  Added more information. The artifact generated has the folder structure as "\publish\Content\D_C\a\1\s\src\aadsr\aadsr\obj\Release\net461\PubTmp\Out"

Comment: @ShijuSamuel, does the D_C is your agent name, right? Do you mind share the pic about the summary tab of your build pipeline?

Comment: @ShijuSamuel You can see this is my task conguration: https://imgur.com/a/JGrHiLm . If you just want the Out folder in ZIP file, you can just copy it through copy file task. It will only copy Out folder, then publish task will only publish it as ZIP file.